# how to modify header of magento?

Tags: php, html, xml, magento, magento2

Hello  I have one magento website and i want edit header of this website.I don't know how to do it I know only HTML NO PHP OR XML so as per my research I came to know that to edit header I have to edit header.phtml file somehow I found that file in my hosting but it has some php and xml code but at the end it has something like`<?php echo $block->getChildHtml();` So where I will get this getChildHTML();. I have HTML header created I just want to add that html file in this function please help me. My header.phtml file located in `public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml`

My header.phtml file source code:

```
    <?php

$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
?>


<?php switch ($block->getShowPart()):
    case 'welcome': ?>
        <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
            <span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome, %1!', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
            <span data-bind="html:'<?=$block->escapeHtml($welcomeMessage) ?>'"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </li>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php break; ?>

    <?php case 'other': ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
    <?php break; ?>

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Comment: Each Block has its own phtml file. You have to find the one that fits your particular block. So getChildHTML() just means that the header file checks back for the Blocks own phtml file. You can't just add an HTML file, because there will always be PHP in it for the dynamic content.

Comment: how can i do that check i have added my header.phtml code

Comment: What do you mean by *header* ... the HTML header (as between `<head> ... </head>` tags or a page header (`<header> ... </header>`) ? You can do a certain amount in the HTML head through System > Configuration > General > Design without touching the templates.

Comment: I want to modify header which contains logo search bar and navigation menu

Comment: Odds are that'll be in several files - the search for instance is likely to be in the `module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates` directory somewhere... best way I've found to actually find anything in Magento is to do a global search, across the entire codebase, for an identifying CSS class. Find that class in a .phtml file and you've likely found the code you need. Don't edit the core magento version though, copy the template into your own theme/module and work on that,.

Comment: As an aside - the code you're showing there just controls the *"Welcome Fred Bloggs"* message - nothing else.